# Why do I get `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')` when running 'db.collections' in js code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm a very beginner with MongoDB and JS

i'm running `nodemon app` in the terminal
running MONGODB COMPASS in the background

I'm getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')
> at D:\Coding\MongoDB\MongoDB Tutorial\app.js:23:24`

afaik I'm supposed to write `db.collections` and not `db.books` directly like I do it in Mongo Shell

db.js

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')

let dbConnection;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(url);

let dbName = 'bookstore'
module.exports = {
  // establish connection to the db
  connectToDb: async (cb) => {
    await client.connect()
      .then(client => {
        dbConnection = client.db(dbName)
        return cb()
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return cb()
      })
  },

  // return connection to the db
  getDb: () => dbConnection
}
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const { connectToDb, getDb } = require('./db')

// init app & middleware
const app = express();

// db connection
let db
let PORT = 3000;
connectToDb((err)=>{
  if (!err) {    
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`app listening on port ${PORT}`);
    });
  db = getDb();
  }
})

// routes
app.get('/books', async (req, res) => {

  // db.books   in mongosh
  const abc = await db.collection('books').find({});
  console.log(abc);

  res.json({ msg: 'Welcome to the api' })
})
```

Comment: so means `db` is undefined. So sounds like db is not being initiailized.

Comment: @epascarello hello thanks for replying. Could you please point out where exactly `db` seems to be undefined/needs to be defined
since i have initialized db in both `db.js` as well as `app.js` where relevant

Comment: where? It is where you use it. `db.collection` so it is complaining that it is undefined. So I am assuming that the part above where you set the variable is either not running or there is an error so it is not going into the if statement. debug it.

Comment: Note that `connectToDb` always calls the callback with no arguments, so `if (!err)` will always be true.